# Does the react-redux connect cause rerender?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I have a component in which there is no componentWillRecieveProps and no other function is changing the state, despite that whenever the store is updating, the component(wrapped in connect) is getting rerendered(which is what I want but i dont understand how without state it is happening). I know connect supplies the component with the new props if they have changed but can this cause the component to rerender?

Comment: Can you share simplified code of component? In case if you pass some props,react will calculate the difference when you'll pass new props to the component, so it will rebuild it's virtual DOM, and propagate the difference to your real DOM. (It is called reconciliation process in react). And it has nothing to do with redux here, it's just plain react

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The short answer is that yes, a change in props will cause a component to re-render.  It might be helpful to look at the lifecycle method [`shouldComponentUpdate`](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#shouldcomponentupdate).  This function will be called by React every time either `props` or `state` change to determine whether the component should re-render.  It looks like this:

```
shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState) {
    // return boolean
}
```

If it returns true, then the component will update, if it returns false, there will not be a re-render.

If we don't add this method to our component, then the default implementation is used, which is simply:

```
shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState) {
    return true;
}
```

I.e. always update on props/state changes.

Occasionally it can be useful for a performance reason to implement some logic in this lifecycle method to only update when necessary, but the majority of the time the default (always return true) works fine.